# Check if string contains substring from a list

Tags: chai

I'm using Chai.js writing some automation tests. I have a string:

`url(http://somewhere.com/images/myimage.png)`

I want to do something like:

`expect(thatSelectedItem).contains.any('jpg', 'png', 'gif')`

However can't seem to find anything in chai.js

Any have any suggestions - read the page http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/ however no luck.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With plain Chai (no additional plugins), you can use [`match`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_match):

```
expect(thatSelectedItem).to.match(/(?:jpg|png|gif)/)
```

Comment: That's not a URL, that's a string containing a URL :D See my edit (removed the `$` from the regular expression so it does a substring match instead of a suffix match).

Comment: Ah yes, I agree, apologies, my bad.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
expect(thatSelectedItem).to.contain.oneOf(['jpg', 'png', 'gif'])
```

---

This lands with [v4.3.0](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/releases/tag/4.3.0) ([docs](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_oneof)). `oneOf` can be chained with `contain`, `contains`, `include` and `includes`, which will work with both arrays and strings. It's strongly recommended to use because the error messages you get with it are much cleaner.